# Pandas não encontra arquivo

Tags: python, pandas

Estou usando o pandas no Python para ler um arquivo CSV que está no meu computador, porém aparece uma mensagem de erro, parece que ele não encontra o arquivo:

```
 import pandas as pd 

 reclamacoes = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Reinaldo\Documents\Jornalismo_de_dados\Justica\reclamacoes\2017-1sem1.csv",sep=';')
```

> ```
> IOErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-4-685400fce544> in <module>()
> ----> 1 reclamacoes = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Reinaldo\Documents\Jornalismo_de_dados\Justica\reclamacoes\2017-1sem1.csv",sep=';')
>
> c:\cygwin64\home\reinaldo\code\justica\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc
> ```
>
> in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names,
>   index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine,
>   converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
>   decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment,
>   encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines,
>   skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray,
>   compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>           653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>           654 
>       --> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>           656 
>           657     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> ```
> c:\cygwin64\home\reinaldo\code\justica\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc
> ```
>
> in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>           403 
>           404     # Create the parser.
>       --> 405     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>           406 
>           407     if chunksize or iterator:
>
> ```
> c:\cygwin64\home\reinaldo\code\justica\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc
> ```
>
> in **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
>           762             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
>           763 
>       --> 764         self._make_engine(self.engine)
>           765 
>           766     def close(self):
>
> ```
> c:\cygwin64\home\reinaldo\code\justica\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc
> ```
>
> in _make_engine(self, engine)
>           983     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
>           984         if engine == 'c':
>       --> 985             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>           986         else:
>           987             if engine == 'python':
>
> ```
> c:\cygwin64\home\reinaldo\code\justica\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc
> ```
>
> in **init**(self, src, **kwds)
>          1603         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
>          1604 
>       -> 1605         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>          1606 
>          1607         # XXX
>
> ```
> pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
> ```
>
> (pandas_libs\parsers.c:4209)()
>
> ```
> pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
> ```
>
> (pandas_libs\parsers.c:8873)()
>
> ```
> eclamacoes�7-1sem1.csv does not existnaldo\Documents\Jornalismo_de_dados\Justica
> ```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

O arquivo pode ser baixado aqui: http://dados.gov.br/dataset/reclamacoes-do-consumidor-gov-br1/resource/1d0e048b-6a14-47e0-8145-3dace76185ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou um tanto quanto enferrujado quanto a Python, mas tenho quase certeza que `\` (barra invertida) é usada para "escapar", se for o caso mude para `/`, assim:

```
import pandas as pd 

reclamacoes = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Reinaldo/Documents/Jornalismo_de_dados/Justica/reclamacoes/2017-1sem1.csv",sep=';')
```

Comment: @13dev, não tem haver com windows ou linux, quase todas linguagens modernas interpretam `/` tanto em linux, unix e windows.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta Adicionar `r` no inicio da string:

```
import pandas as pd 
reclamacoes = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Reinaldo\Documents\Jornalismo_de_dados\Justica\reclamacoes\2017-1sem1.csv',sep=';')
```

O `r` significa **[carriage return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed)**.

> O carriage return significa retornar linha atual sem
>   avançar para baixo. O nome vem da carruagem da impressora, já que os
>   monitores eram raros quando o nome estava cunhado. Isso é comummente
>   escapado como " r", abreviado CR e tem ASCII valor 13 ou 0x0D.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando **pwd** para descobrir onde o Jupyter Notebook está sendo executado.

Por padrão, o sistema irá buscar o arquivo nesse diretório.

Para ler em uma pasta diferente, você precisa colocar o caractere " .. "  que server para ler o arquivo em um diretório pai.

Exemplo:

```
arquivo_text = pd.read_csv("../Subpasta1/Subpasta2/arquivo.csv", sep=';')
```